# jQuery Bounce Effect with css styling issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have [this scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy6h7/35/) - where I am trying to create a 'hovering' link. (hover over image, then mouseout and wait ~3seconds to see it 'jump' back instead of jQuery animation)

```
+-----------+
|  I        |
|   M       |
|     A     |    <-- image (acts as as link)
|      G    |  
|        E  |
+-----------+

 ___________    <-- shadow effect
```

I currently have a css hover effect, as well as a `::after` css system to create this shadow, 
which is *meant* to raise the image up slightly, shrink the width of the 'shadow', and also 'lighten' the shadow (which sort of works).

I am now trying to add a JQuery 'Bounce' into the mix when the mouse leaves the link. However, Due to the transition from the css, I don't think gets fired (or something doesn't work - either way, it doesn't work).

I am then having the issue of ensuring this is dynamic, allowing **different sized** images to be used as the links (with multiples along the width of the page). And so I am trying to use the width of the parent to be the width of the shadow (which doesn't work, so have excluded the %'s from this example.

My links **may** look something like this once complete:

```
                          +------------+
+-----------+             |            |
|           |             |            |
|           |             |            |   +---+
|           |   +---+     |            |   |   |
|           |   |   |     |            |   +---+
+-----------+   +---+     +------------+

_____________   _____     ______________     _

                                             ^
                                             |
                                          hovered
```

My current JQuery:

```
 $(".topMenuImg").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 'normal');
        }, function () {
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 'normal');
          });
```

---

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy6h7/37/) shows the **actual** css currently used (not perfect).

inserting the Jquery also messes things up A LOT: [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy6h7/38/)

---

Any comments/suggestions/clarifications much appreciated on this matter.

This picture is showing the 'hover' effect presently:

[image]

Comment: So when do you need bounce? Do you want it only once on hover?

Comment: No, I wish to have both. On hover, raise, on mouse exit, 'bounce' to original position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```js
 $(".topMenuImg").mouseout(function() {
   $(this).find('.myImg').stop().effect("bounce", {
     direction: 'down',
     times: 3
   }, 400);

 });
```

```css
.topMenuImg {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.25%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80%;
  width: 7.5%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.topMenuImg:hover {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.topMenuImg:after {
  /*This is the shadow effect*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.10);
  transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.80);
  padding-left: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.topMenuImg:hover:after {
  /*Also shadow effect*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 8%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.40);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 4px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 4px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 4px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 4px);
  transform: translate(0, 4px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="topMenuImg">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRM4sZx4tVSdA8DTRHrjZ79l5yVMB5LiwsrhTClLdoxOl8LnsAnmQ" />
</div>

<br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have edited your answer to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f9hraug2/1/), but still doesn't fully 'suit' due to the shadow not quite fitting in.

Comment: What do you want the shadow to do?

Comment: would need to lighten/darken depending on 'distance' of the bounce - as the image goes down, the shadow darkens and vice versa. Not too worried about the size of the shadow (as explained in question)  - but would be nice to have the shadow have the darken/lighten to the images 'bounce'